# How to query time-series data when DB time-slice is bigger than wanted time-slice?

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

How to query time-slices out of data, when db time-slice is bigger than wanted time-slice. End result will be used to draw stacked bar graph.

Example data:

```
START_TS (int)| END_TS (int) | DATA (int) | GROUP
-----------------------------------
0       | 179      | 2000  | G1
180     | 499      | 1000  | G2
500     | 699      | 1000  | G1
845 ...
```

Wanted output using time-slice as 100 "units". End_ts is not needed in output but helps to understand the calculations.

```
START_TS |  END_TS  | DATA (equation = amount in that time slice) | GROUP
-------------------------------------------------------
0       |    99   | (2000 / 180) * 100 =  1111 | G1
100     |   199   | (2000 / 180) *  80 =   889 | G1
100     |   199   | (1000 / 320) *  20 =    63 | G2
200     |   299   | (1000 / 320) * 100 =   313 | G2 
300     |   399   | (1000 / 320) * 100 =   313 | G2
400     |   499   | (1000 / 320) * 100 =   313 | G2
```

Getting time-series out of this is something like this.

```
SELECT (startts/100)*100, ...
FROM TABLE
    FULL JOIN
        ( SELECT startts from generate_series(0,700,100) startts ) s1
    USING (startts)
GROUP BY  startts/100
```

So it would be something like this (without group by)

```
 STARTTS | ENDTS | DATA | GROUP
   0     | 179      | 2000   | G1
   100   |      
   180   | 499      | 1000   | G2
   200   |
   300   |
   400   | 
   500   | 699      | 1000   | G1
   600   |
   700
```

But how do I split DATA in to two or more generated rows (time-slice rows), to be calculated in time-slices.

---

** This basically works, but not really functional on big dataset. rows like 1-100M rows.

Here is the query to do it + some more to aggregate values which does not overlap time-slice

```
SELECT (start_ts/100)*100 as start_ts, sum(part) as data, cgroup
FROM (
SELECT *, ( data * (overlap_end-overlap_start + 1 ) / ( end_ts - tts + 1 ) ) as part
FROM 
    (
    SELECT (case when s1.start_ts > t.start_ts then s1.start_ts else t.start_ts end) as overlap_start,
        (case when s1.start_ts+100 < t.end_ts then s1.start_ts+100-1 else t.end_ts end) as overlap_end,
        t.start_ts as tts, s1.start_ts as start_ts, t.end_ts, cgroup, data
    FROM (SELECT start_ts from generate_series(0,800,100) start_ts ) s1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN test t on t.start_ts < s1.start_ts+100 and t.end_ts >= s1.start_ts
    ) t
) t2
GROUP BY start_ts/100, cgroup
```

Comment: You have a 'duplicate' desired row (`START_TS = 100, END_TS = 199`) - do you want this to be aggregated with the other portion?  Also, you're aware that any splits you do will be completely fabricated/averaged, right?  Because you don't know _when_ during the time-slice they originally happened; it's like a tourist wondering why the guidebook says 'bring a coat', when the average yearly temperature is 90F - it's just the one day a year that's 40F.  It's usually best to construct this sort of thing from the original data - is it available?

Comment: Yes I want to have two start_ts values in "100" slice, as they will present each groups value in that slice. I am aware that it will fabricate / average results, but this is wanted feature now. I am drawing stacked bar or actually stacked line graph, where each line are 1pixel width and stacked with all groups in that slice. Original data might will be around, but that comes in to use only after certain zooming level has reached and is out of this question.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to split different timeslots into bins, defined by the sequence.  The following query does this by modifying the join condition and calculating the overlap between the two:

```
SELECT (startts/100)*100, ...
from (select (case when s1.starts > t.start_ts then s1.starts else t.start_t2 end) as overlap_start,
             (case when s1.starts+100 < t.end_ts then s1.starts+100-1 else t.end_ts end) as overlap_end,
             ts.*
      FROM (SELECT startts from generate_series(0,700,100) startts ) s1 left outer join
           TABLE t
           on t.startts < s1.starts+100 and
              t.end_ts >= s1.starts
     ) t
```

Comment: **Absolutely amazing**, this does it, thanks. Even tough I can read and understand the query, it somehow does not fit in to my head, so that I could form one yet. SQL is somehow so mystical.

Comment: Overlapping time periods are hard to visualize.

Comment: There seems to be one problem with real data. Data set is big, 1-100M rows, so this approach will be way too slow.

Comment: I don't know the performance characteristics of `generate_series`.  However, if the result has just a handful of rows (tens), then this approach should be fine.  You might try instantiating the series in a table to see if that helps.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I've found that generate_series() is often faster than using a table, but you have to test with your own data.  Cardinality, width of rows in bytes (number of rows that fit in a page), etc., can all affect the speed.  I haven't tested in PostgreSQL 9.2 yet--covering indexes might change the performance of tables a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d8107/2). It shows all calculated columns at each step just for clarity.

```
with data_avg as (
    select start_ts, end_ts, "data" * 1.0 / ((end_ts + 1) - start_ts) data_avg
    from test
), gs as (
    select start_ts, start_ts + 99 end_ts
    from generate_series(
        (select min(start_ts) from test),
        (select max(end_ts) from test),
        100
    ) gs(start_ts)
)
select 
    t_start, t_end,
    gs_start, gs_end,
    cgroup,
    s."start", s."end",
    da.start_ts da_start, da.end_ts da_end
    ,round((s."end" - s."start" + 1) * da.data_avg) "data"
from (
    select
        t.start_ts t_start, t.end_ts t_end,
        gs.start_ts gs_start, gs.end_ts gs_end,
        cgroup,
        greatest(t.start_ts, gs.start_ts) "start", least(t.end_ts, gs.end_ts) "end"
    from
        test t
        inner join
        gs on
            gs.start_ts between t.start_ts and t.end_ts
            or
            gs.end_ts between t.start_ts and t.end_ts
    ) s
    inner join
    data_avg da on
        da.start_ts between t_start and t_end
        and
        da.end_ts between t_start and t_end
order by s."start"
```

The result:

```
 t_start | t_end | gs_start | gs_end | cgroup | start | end | da_start | da_end | data 
---------+-------+----------+--------+--------+-------+-----+----------+--------+------
       0 |   179 |        0 |     99 | G1     |     0 |  99 |        0 |    179 | 1111
       0 |   179 |      100 |    199 | G1     |   100 | 179 |        0 |    179 |  889
     180 |   499 |      100 |    199 | G2     |   180 | 199 |      180 |    499 |   63
     180 |   499 |      200 |    299 | G2     |   200 | 299 |      180 |    499 |  313
     180 |   499 |      300 |    399 | G2     |   300 | 399 |      180 |    499 |  313
     180 |   499 |      400 |    499 | G2     |   400 | 499 |      180 |    499 |  313
     500 |   699 |      500 |    599 | G1     |   500 | 599 |      500 |    699 |  500
     500 |   699 |      600 |    699 | G1     |   600 | 699 |      500 |    699 |  500
```